# Implementing ShowDialog() style functionality without disabling any other windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I need a simple prompt window to ask the user to do something with an OK/Cancel return. But I also need all Windows to remain functional, so a xx.ShowDialog isn't appropriate.

This is my attempt. DialogWindow takes a Delegate in the constructor and calls it when *OK* or *Cancel* is clicked with a True/False parameter respectively. The Window is coded to take top Z priority.

It seems to work but I'm not very knowledgeable on await usage. Is there an easier way?

```
        bool result;
        ManualResetEvent manualReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        DialogWindow myDialog = new DialogWindow((dialogResult) =>
        {
            result = dialogResult;
            manualReset.Set();
        });
        myDialog.Show();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            manualReset.WaitOne();
        });
        //Do something with result
```

Comment: You could do the same by making sure the `TopMost` property of the dialog form is set to true.  Now the `Show()` method will place the dialog on top and any other forms can still take focus.  Once a new dialog form is instantiated you can access any of its controls and properties that aren't private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ManualResetEvent` this way means that you're blocking a thread unnecessarily while the dialog is shown. Instead, you should use [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174), which allows you to create a `Task` that completes when you want it to.

Encapsulated into a method, the code could look something like this:

```
public static Task<bool> ShowAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var dialog = new DialogWindow(tcs.SetResult);
    dialog.Show();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```